# UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid

Tags: conda, miniconda

While installing packages I get the following `UnavailableInvalidChannel` error:

```
conda install openai
Collecting package metadata: failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: pkgs/main
  channel url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

Now I did:

```
conda config --show channels
channels:
  - defaults
```

I dont understand why conda is broken with `pkgs/main`. There is no such channels.

Also tried:

```
conda config --remove channels pkgs/main

CondaKeyError: 'channels': 'pkgs/main' is not in the 'channels' key of the config file
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [conda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-professional/troubleshooting/#error), this is either an internet issue or a misconfigured .condarc file. Fortunately, the fixes are pretty straightforward.